# Why is token based authentication better for Single Page Applications?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, token, jwt, single-page-application

Okay so this might be a very rookie-ish or naive question but I tried searching the internet and have resorted to stack overflow only after not finding anything fruitful. I have been reading about Token based authentication as well as Cookie based authentication. I have come across the opinion that token based authentication is better for Single page web applications but cannot clearly understand why. I will be using nodejs and angularjs to accomplish the same.

Comment: check this out if its help u -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825060/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pass-an-authentication-token-back-to-the-client/44825264?noredirect=1#comment76631473_44825264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that with *Token based authentication as well as Cookie based authentication* you mean **Token authentication vs Session authentication** because a token can be stored in a cookie

See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/92123/112160)

- With **session based authentication** the server maintains a sessions per each connected user. Client authenticates with its credentials and receives a session_id (which can be stored in a cookie) and attaches this to every subsequent outgoing request. So this could be considered a "token" as it is the equivalent of a set of credentials. This approach requires heavy server resources
- **Token based authentication** is stateless and does not require server storage because the issued token (mainly JWT is used) contains the relevant user info and is signed with the server private key, so it is non-falsifiable. The token is stored in client side (cookie, localStorage, etc), attached to every request and validated by the server. Tokens are also suitable for REST APIs that do not require to maintain the state between each request

Forms based applications use session based authentication, and SPA often use token based authentication by the inherent advantages.

Note also that a SPA with session based authentication only will attach cookies to the outgoing request if the applicacion is located in the same domain that the server

Answer (score 3):

SPAs tend to have many faces: the logged in view, the logged out view, or the restricted view. It’s all about access control. Your users are all getting the same app but they may not have the same levels of access. You’ll find yourself building access control logic for your front end and your back end.

Because tokens contain all this information, they are very portable: they can be used by your UI and your backend to make decisions. You can share them with partner services as a means of building Single Sign On services that delegate users to the correct application.

Hope this link will give you more information..

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa)

Comment: In general in SO, do not include links as  answers because the content may change and readers have to do the effort of understand how the link answers the question. If you think  that a link could be helpful, summarize it, relate it with the question and, of course, post the link

Comment: Ok. I will review my answer